# Unable to read excel sheet data on server to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

In my web based project I need to upload an excel sheet and store the data in database. The code works fine on my local machine.

However when I try to execute same code on server the data of the
excel sheet doesn't get stored in my database.

I have given relevant folder permission on server.

```
 foreach (string s in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
            int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string fileExtension = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);


            savedFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
            filename = Server.MapPath("~/Stockfiles/") + savedFileName;

            // Place your code here to save information in database.

            // Save the stream to disk
            file.SaveAs(filename);
            string conString = string.Empty;
            switch (fileExtension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString;
                    break;

            }
            conString = string.Format(conString, filename);
            using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = null;
                excel_con.Open();
                string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

                //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
                dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("PhoneIMEI", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("PhonePrice",typeof(string)),new DataColumn("barcode",typeof(string))});

                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
                {
                    oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                }

                excel_con.Close();


                string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                {

                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = con.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, sqlTransaction))
                        {
                            //Set the database table name
                            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Stock ";

                            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                            //sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PhoneIMEI", "PhoneIMEI");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PhonePrice", "PhonePrice");
                            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("barcode", "barcode");
                            try
                            {
                                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                                //SqlCommand getcount = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from dbo.Stock ", con);

                                sqlTransaction.Commit();
                                con.Close();
                                //file.SaveAs(filename);
}
```

Web.Config Code

```
<connectionStrings>   
    <add name="Excel03ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
    <add name="Excel07+ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we need to install Microsoft office in server for Excel import in Asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702788/do-we-need-to-install-microsoft-office-in-server-for-excel-import-in-asp-net)

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No I'm not getting any error .