# Insert one million of objects with "Add" to List is slowly

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I do not have problems when the records are at most 200 thousand, but when the records exceed one million, it takes a long time to enter the data to the list called "list". (I waited 30 minutes and still did not finish inserting the list)
What is this doing wrong?
Will there be any way to return a list or arrangement with more than 1 million records?

Note: return to list and then go through and download that list in an excel (I did not attach the code because it stays stuck in the point I explained)

```
var list = new List<DataClass>();       
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("PROCEDURE_HERE", sqlConnection))
{
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Field_1", dataInput_field1);
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            list.Add( new DataClass {
                   response_1 = sqlDataReader["Nombre"].ToString(),
                   response_2 = sqlDataReader["correlativo_sgrc"].ToString(),
                   response_3 = sqlDataReader["rut"].ToString(),
                   response_4 = sqlDataReader["Celular"].ToString(),
                   response_5 = sqlDataReader["fecha_envio"].ToString(),
                   response_6 = sqlDataReader["hora_envio"].ToString(),
                   response_7 = sqlDataReader["mensaje"].ToString()
               });
        } 
    }
};
```

EDIT: I explain the flow:

1. Search the data with a store procedure (sp) in database
2. Obtain the data of sp and save into the list (is the code that I paste here)
3. Return the list and use it for create a excel file with the class
   ExcelWorksheet (for download a report)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you wanna have a million records in a list?

Comment: Instead of adding the data to a list (which is extremely fast, the problem is in the reading, not in adding the items), you could stream the results back to the caller using `yield return new DataClass ...`

Comment: If you know how many objects are going to be in the list (say 1.2 million), try creating the list with a capacity: `var list = new List<DataClass>(1_200_000);`  If you just create the list and add _a lot_ of things to it, it has to grow over and over again.

Comment: If you know you're going to have a very large list, creating it at roughly the right size (or over) will stop a lot of re-allocations / block-copies. But... 1M should work fine... I regularly work with 10M row buffers, no problem. But, to avoid GC from hurting me, I work with `readonly struct` when I do that...

Comment: @jdweng `SqlBulkCopy` is for putting data into the database, not getting it out

Comment: BTW, if you only use list to populate excel - you don't need it. you can go from reader directly to excel. You can use Excel as regular data table if you use microsoft.ace.ole db driver

Comment: - I insert in List for use it in a excel file for user (reports of two months).
 
- my CPU is in 100% now while insert to List and don't stop , the database is a server (not my host)  

Folks, I use the list because I will use it after for download report in excel (this list is the data for excel)

@Flydog57 try it, still the same

Comment: Is the insertion into a `List<T>` taking forever, or the work to get it into Excel.  How are you creating you Excel file?  For example, if you are using OpenXML (creating it cell by cell with the object model rather than the XML-ish API), it doesn't scale that well.

Comment: One other thing to consider is that accessing the contents of a DataReader using the column name (as you do) requires a string lookup for every field and every row. It's "quick and dirty" if you have a handful of rows. For a million, get the (integer) ordinal values for each column and use those integers rather than the strings.

Comment: You are saying SP is not a problem. Fetching millions record means your machine configuration has to be strong.Though SqlDatareader is good choice once you can try DataTable.Even if somehow you succeed ,exporting millions to excel is again tough,you hv to use CSV file then.I think you should SSIS package.

Comment: *"I insert in List for use it in a excel file for user"* - so you do take data from SqlServer and fill Excel. **You don't need List to do this.** Go from sql server directly to excel via `microsof.ace.oledb.xx` provider. And there are plenty of examples on SO, CodeProject etc. This is like taking data from 1 db to another.

Answer (score 0):

(This wouldn't fit as a comment and sort of an answer after all)

I just tried your code (slightly correcting the typos and instead of an SP using an SQL statement) with 5,000,000 records and loaded the list in 12 seconds. Instead of all those ToString() I casted the types (ie: MyField = (int)sqlDataReader["MyField"]). Had 4 fields (Guid, string, int and decimal) and timed on a Phenom II X6 1090T with 16Gb RAM, database on 7200 RPM 500Gb disk and the server was SQL Express 2012. IOW, I don't think that your bottleneck is reading the data nor populating the list.

You are saying "go through and download that list in an excel". First populating a list to load to excel is not only unnecessary but very slow operation by nature. I think the code you didn't include had excel COM calls in it and it is slow. Doing 1 million of them you are guaranteed to wait and wait if it ever finishes.

There are multiple much faster ways to get the data to excel and probably the fastest is to use Excel's QueryTables.Add method. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add();
    xl.Visible = true;

    Worksheet sht = ((Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet);
    Range target = (Range)sht.Range["A1"];

    string strCon = @"ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes";
    string strSQL = "select * from MyTable";
    var qt = sht.QueryTables.Add(strCon, target, strSQL);
    qt.Refresh();
}
```

A code like this ran in 2 seconds on my system, and in Excel it started getting external data, which completed in 20 seconds for 1 million rows.

(And always keep in mind excel is not a database)

EDIT: As T.S. claimed this to be a bad approach and suggested using ACE.OLEDB insertion instead I got my time testing some approaches (although I knew from my experience already, I was ready to stand corrected).

This part discusses about 3 ways to get the data to Excel from SQL server. I used the same data from SQL server for these tests, each time selecting **same 1 million rows**:

1. QueryTables.Add approach was the fastest. Elapsed - **00:00:29.7767063**
2. Insert data using Epplus from NuGet. This one doesn't need Excel to be installed if that is your concern. In this one, unlike the other two approaches I used Linq to get the data as a collection. Slower than 1st approach but not bad at all. Elapsed - **00:00:37.7340975**
3. This one is the **worst** approach of these three. Used ACE.OleDb to insert the data using the code that T.S provided the link. As expected it was awfully slow. Its timing was unacceptable but anyway I timed. Elapsed - **00:11:52.7427790**

Go figure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I change the data type like ( myfield = (string)sqlDataReader["data"] ) but still is the same. 
My problem is in that code, specifically in while loop ( while (sqlDataReader.Read()) ), never finish. But... with records less than 500 thousend works fine. 

I don't use excel like database, I use a store procedure for obtain data, after I save the data in list and finally use ExcelWorksheet class  for use the data into excel file

Comment: @GedwardRomo, if your problem is really in that code then there is something wrong in your server. As I said, I filled 5 million rows list in 12 seconds. You didn't give the definition of DataClass either.

Comment: **Bad Approach**

Comment: @T.S. what is bad approach?

Comment: Use of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` in this project is bad approach

Comment: @T.S. Would you please explain why is that? It is probably the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Expensive, heavy, version-dependent, non scalable and not advised by MS themselves. What needs to be done - use excel as db table and fill it using simple `while reader.read()` loop. In this case, code is light, little resources are used, it is scalable because it is can be deployed not only on desktop but also on web server or any server. No excel install needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702788/do-we-need-to-install-microsoft-office-in-server-for-excel-import-in-asp-net

Comment: @T.S. :) Why wouldn't show us some sample working code to do that. You are just making assumptions. You could also use Epplus without installing excel but that doesn't mean it is better. FWIW reader.Read() approach has never been a better approach.

Comment: I am not going to reinvent the wheel here. It is invented and widely used. I am not answering the question to write code again. Examples are aplenty. With your approach you can only do one excel at the time, can't do server, requires installation of software. There is enough evidence and experience to say, this is bad approach for this specific OP need. I rest my case

Comment: @T.S., maybe at least a reference link to the invented wheel?

Comment: Check this https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB

Comment: @T.S. Bad approach :)

Comment: elaborate, why?

Comment: @T.S. check the link you gave carefully.

Comment: @T.S. I wasted some time for you, thinking you might still haven't been able to see what is bad in that approach. I will now 'EDIT' my reply to elaborate why it was bad.

Comment: I am glad that you proved that **epplus** is faster than `ace.oledb`. This however doesn't change the point that using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` for this problem is bad approach. The speed is only one thing to consider. You totally disregarding lack of scalability and other aforementioned factors. Besides, such processes happen in off hours and if server runs these, using `interop` is no go. Everything has its place and time. Golden hammer is an antipattern.

Comment: @T.S. interop is a GOOD approach. The speed is only one thing to consider, right. But it still has plusses, you can do the most with Excel IF you are using interop. I am not disregarding scalability or other factors, I simply don't understand what you are talking about. For example, scalability and Excel. Please explain that and other non-existent factors. How come Excel is scalable if you use ACE.OLEDB or Epplus? Give me a solid sample if possible this time.  To me it looks like you just don't want to stand corrected.

Comment: *"..it looks like you just don't want to stand corrected"* -quite contrary. I liked to hear EpPlus library can be very fast, & I'll keep it in mind. Your answer for THIS problem, should be wrapped around EpPlus, not interop. Interop has some real disadvantages and you should read carefully because I listed them. If I was to develop a DLL that just moves data using Excel workbooks, I wouln't consider interop - it is not useful in web applications or multi-process services. Are you going to start Excel App on web server? Are you satisfied that you can do only one data process at the time?

Comment: @T.S. what have you listed :) You are again making assumptions around your 'beliefs' and 'preferences' rather than solid facts. Instead of asking questions, show the answers in code. How come you came to web server from OP's question? How come you reasoned you could do one data process at a time? Why aren't you questioning SQL server if you are so eager about scalability? This discussion has no end. I agree to disagree. Interop is a GOOD approach for OP question. Period.